# Databricks - Delta Live Table Pipeline - Ingest Kafka Avro using Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, databricks, avro, confluent-schema-registry, delta-live-tables

I'm new to Azure Databricks and I'm trying implement an Azure Databricks Delta Live Table Pipeline that ingests from a Kafka topic containing messages where the values are SchemaRegistry encoded AVRO.

## Work done so far...

### Exercise to Consume and Write to a Delta Table

Using the example in [Confluent Example](https://www.confluent.io/en-gb/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/#step-7), I've read the "raw" message via:

```
rawAvroDf = (
  spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", confluentBootstrapServers)
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='{}' password='{}';".format(confluentApiKey, confluentSecret))
  .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https")
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
  .option("subscribe", confluentTopicName)
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .load()
  .withColumn('key', fn.col("key").cast(StringType()))
  .withColumn('fixedValue', fn.expr("substring(value, 6, length(value)-5)"))
  .withColumn('valueSchemaId', binary_to_string(fn.expr("substring(value, 2, 4)")))
  .select('topic', 'partition', 'offset', 'timestamp', 'timestampType', 'key', 'valueSchemaId','fixedValue')
)
```

Created a SchemaRegistryClient:

```
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
import ssl

schema_registry_conf = {
    'url': schemaRegistryUrl,
    'basic.auth.user.info': '{}:{}'.format(confluentRegistryApiKey, confluentRegistrySecret)}

schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_registry_conf)
```

Defined a deserialization function that looks up the schema ID from the start of the binary message:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.avro.functions import from_avro

def parseAvroDataWithSchemaId(df, ephoch_id):
  cachedDf = df.cache()
  
  fromAvroOptions = {"mode":"FAILFAST"}
  
  def getSchema(id):
    return str(schema_registry_client.get_schema(id).schema_str)

  distinctValueSchemaIdDF = cachedDf.select(fn.col('valueSchemaId').cast('integer')).distinct()

  for valueRow in distinctValueSchemaIdDF.collect():

    currentValueSchemaId = sc.broadcast(valueRow.valueSchemaId)
    currentValueSchema = sc.broadcast(getSchema(currentValueSchemaId.value))
    
    filterValueDF = cachedDf.filter(fn.col('valueSchemaId') == currentValueSchemaId.value)
    
    filterValueDF \
      .select('topic', 'partition', 'offset', 'timestamp', 'timestampType', 'key', from_avro('fixedValue', currentValueSchema.value, fromAvroOptions).alias('parsedValue')) \
      .write \
      .format("delta") \
      .mode("append") \
      .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
     .save(deltaTablePath)
```

Finally written to a delta table:

```
rawAvroDf.writeStream \
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath) \
  .foreachBatch(parseAvroDataWithSchemaId) \
  .queryName("clickStreamTestFromConfluent") \
  .start()
```

### Created a (Bronze/Landing) Delta Live Table

```
import dlt
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

@dlt.table(
    name = "<<landingTable>>",
    path = "<<storage path>>",
    comment = "<< descriptive comment>>"
)
def landingTable():
    jasConfig = "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='{}' password='{}';".format(confluentApiKey, confluentSecret)
    
    binary_to_string = fn.udf(lambda x: str(int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='big')), StringType())
    
    kafkaOptions = {
      "kafka.bootstrap.servers": confluentBootstrapServers,
      "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
      "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": jasConfig,
      "kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm": "https",
      "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
      "subscribe": confluentTopicName,
      "startingOffsets": "earliest",
      "failOnDataLoss": "false"
    }
    
    return (
        spark
            .readStream
            .format("kafka")
            .options(**kafkaOptions)
            .load()
            .withColumn('key', fn.col("key").cast(StringType()))
            .withColumn('valueSchemaId', binary_to_string(fn.expr("substring(value, 2, 4)")))
            .withColumn('avroValue', fn.expr("substring(value, 6, length(value)-5)"))
            .select(
                'topic',
                'partition',
                'offset',
                'timestamp',
                'timestampType',
                'key',
                'valueSchemaId',
                'avroValue'
            )
```

## Help Required on:

1. Ensure that the landing table is a `STREAMING LIVE TABLE`
2. Deserialize the avro encode message-value (a `STREAMING LIVE VIEW` calling a python UDF?)

Comment: is your schema registry with authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Package to install: `confluent-kafka[avro,json,protobuf]>=1.4.2`

```
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient

schema_registry_conf = {
    'url': schemaRegistryUrl,
    'basic.auth.user.info': '{}:{}'.format(schemaRegistryUser, schemaRegistryPassword)}

schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_registry_conf)

topic_name = 'xxxxxxxxxx'

latest_schema = schema_registry_client.get_latest_version(topic_name + '-value').schema.schema_str

print(latest_schema)
```

[GitHub link](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/src/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/schema_registry_client.py) for `get_latest_version`